# Binary Search Tree - Delete

Tags: binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a program that takes in strings and places them in a binary search tree in alphabetical order once these are inserted into the tree, a user prompts for one word to be deleted, thus deleting that node from the tree, and then output the tree without that node back in order.

Everything works for this up to the delete function, the delete function does work, but its very weird how it deletes.  I think currently it deletes a full side of the tree, because when I delete the last word, it typically works. I will upload my delete function and if more is needed I can upload the rest of my code.

Thanks!

```
template<typename T> void Delete(TreeNode<T>*& root, const T& data)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
        if(data < root->Value)
            return Delete(root->Left, data);
        else if (root->Value > data)
            return Delete(root->Right, data);
        else
        {
            TreeNode<T>* old_root = root;
            if (root->Left == NULL)
            {
                root = root->Right;
            }
            else if (root->Right == NULL)
            {
                root = root->Left;
            }
            else
            {
                replace_parent(old_root, old_root->Left);
            }
            delete old_root;



    }

};

template<typename T> void replace_parent(TreeNode<T>*& old_root, TreeNode<T>*& root)
{
    if (root->Right != NULL)
    {
        replace_parent(old_root, root->Right);
    }
    else
    {
        old_root->Value = root->Value;
        old_root = root;
        root = root->Left;
    }
};
```

Comment: I would think that the problem is in replace_parent.  Can you post that code?

Comment: There is the replace_parent template, why does it never work when I use the <pre><code> ?

Comment: You click the little button with ones and zeros on it to highlight your selected.

Answer (score 3):

Lacqui is correct in his points.

let me tell you you that while deleting a node you need to replace it with either the max node in left sub tree or the minimum node in the right sub tree. for example:
if you see the below picture:
[image]

if you want to delete the node 90,you need to take care that you replace it with either 80 which is its max node in the left subtree or the 92 which the minimum node in the right sub tree. you can keep any one approach.

so the algo will be :
considering the left sub tree:

->if you find the node to delete,navigate to the max value in its left sub tree.

->assign the node's left as 50 and node right to be 150

->make 75->next as null and delete 90

Comment: How can that be a general rule? What if the lowest value of the right subtree is 1? Then your method won't work!

Comment: The smallest value of the right subtree will never be smaller than the root BECAUSE it's in the right subtree. The answer works for this reason

Answer (score 2):

Your cases for either left or right being `NULL` are good.  However, your logic for neither of them being `NULL` is, unfortunately, failing.

If I'm reading your code (and understanding the function `replace_parent()` correctly, then if neither tree is empty you are replacing the current root with `Left`.

Ask yourself - what is happening to the values that are in the `Right` subtree?

What you need to do in order to delete a node is as follows:

1. Enter one of the subtrees.  It looks like you've chosen your `Left` subtree, so we'll go from there.
2. Follow the *opposite* line of branches.  In this example, keep going down the `Right` subtrees from your original `Left`.  Keep going until you find a right-leaf node (no `Right` subtrees; `Left` is OK)
3. Remember the value of your right-leaf in a `tmp` variable.
4. Transfer the right-leaf's `Left` (whether `NULL` or not) to the right-leaf's position.
5. Take the `tmp` value and put it into your original 'to-delete' node.

Comment: So you believe the problem occurs in the first two 'if' statements?

Comment: I belive it _doesn't_ occur in the first two `if`s.  I'm looking at the final `else`, where the tree still has children; this is the worst-case scenario yet unfortunately the most common.

Comment: If it is the last else, could it be my replace_parent function or is the last else still in need of more coding?

Comment: The problem is in replace_parent.  Rather than moving each element up by one, which you are currently doing, you need to follow the branch all the way to the bottom, and bring the leaf node to the top.  To do otherwise risks your tree ending up out of order.